# Replacing backslashes with forward slashes - Image URL

Tags: php, string, url

I'm trying to remove the backslashes to open the Image URL, I found a way to replace but part of my string was lost:

```
function formatURL( $url )
{    
    echo $url."<br />";

    $url = str_replace('\\', '/', $url);

    echo $url."<br />";
}

echo "http://10.0.0.1/fotoou/aplic\1\7\1\3\9\8\1\\1893171_1.jpg<br />";

$url = formatURL("http://10.0.0.1/fotoou/aplic\1\7\1\3\9\8\1\\1893171_1.jpg");

echo $url;
```

The awkward is that my return is:

```
http://10.0.0.1/fotoou/aplic\9\8\1893171_1.jpg
http://10.0.0.1/fotoou/aplic\9\8\1893171_1.jpg
http://10.0.0.1/fotoou/aplic/9/8/1893171_1.jpg
```

Part of string was lost

```
\1\7\1\3\
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\` starts an escape sequence in PHP. In those places where the data is "lost", the `\` never represented a backslash character. You can't recover it because the data was never there to begin with.

You need to edit the string in the PHP source code, not try to manipulate it after the PHP source has been parsed.